# Prevent spliting on the dimensoin when using LYTD

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have this pbix : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tpGKvL_ST1L7YgDkDFqqLqfKb0FEjfcL/view?usp=sharing

I have a single selection filter on Year, and when I select 2021:

[image]

My goal is to never split a given Customer on Type, so, when I show the totals, I want to see: Net Revenue LYTD as 54 but in Locale, not in Inter:

[image]

I cannot hardcode it... Many clients can belong to the same type.

Also a Customer changing 'type' can happen with more than one Customer in the future (or different type names). The only good thing is: if they switch, they do it on 01-Jan.

Can in DAX somehow force that when using LYTD, the revenue shall stay in the same type as YTD?

My expected output is:

(when 2021 is selected):

[image]

When 2020 is selected... it should work as it is already working:

[image]

Comment: Can you show your sample data and expected output from them?

Comment: There is a link to the pbix, and I just added my expected output.